# Can someone help me start this proof? I dont know how to begin

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ invertible matrices satisfying $AB + BA = O_{n \times n}$, where $O_{n \times n}$ is the $n \times n$ zero matrix. Prove that $n$ must be even.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ invertible matrices satisfying $AB + BA = O_{n \times n}$, where $O_{n \times n}$ is the $n \times n$ zero matrix." ...

To be helpful, I observe that this means $AB = -BA$, so $ABA^{-1} = -B$.  So $B$ and $-B$ are similar.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $AB=-BA$. Compute the determinant of both sides.